# WooCommerce PHP API: Bulk save products

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce, bulk

I wanted to know if it is possible to save multiple products in bulk using the WooCommerce PHP API. I currently have 1000 products that I have to regularly reimport from a CSV file, and when I save them one by one through the `Product` class, it takes >10 minutes. I searched through the [Docs](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/) but didn't find anything.

Comment: Have you tried this [woocommerce product import](https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/) free plugin

Comment: @mujuonly I'm writing a custom plugin as there are some specificities that cannot be achieved with the common importer plugins.

Comment: Their api is pretty slow I must admit, how complex is your import? can you maybe just import changes instead of the whole product? also, take into account that woocommerce suggests to max crud 100 products at a time, and you reached that limit so things might timeout or break if you exceed it

Comment: @Buttered_Toast Yes I could try importing just the changes. But will this work? Considering that all product data gets updated in a single action with the `Product->save()` method. Well I'll try it anyway

Comment: Product->save()?, that's the old, very slow, method. Use their REST API, https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/. will make life much simpler, it also has endpoints for updating content